# Correct grammatical usage of already

Tags: grammar

Can we use this type of formation.

> Stop bluffing. There's no need to hide it. Tell me already

Can already be used in this way.

Answer (score 2):

> Tell me already!

In formal English, **already** means "before now", so it would be unnatural to use it at the end of a request for information... the speaker has not **already** told you.

In German, **schon** means already, but if used at the end of a request or command it also means **come on**! This found its way into Yiddish, as **שוין** (shoyn). When American Yiddish speakers switch to English, they sometimes finish a request with **already**, when they really mean **come on!**. It's the sort of thing that the Marx brothers would say.

From here, it found its way into humorous, informal American English as an expression of impatience. According to the [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/already), it is:

> used to show that you are losing patience and want someone to stop doing something or to do something more quickly

Comment: Thanku but I don't understand whether you are supporting the sentence or not.... Just tell me directly whether already can be used in this way......

Comment: It can't be used in British English,  but can be in American English.

Answer (score 2):

That use of *already* is not only grammatical, but idiomatic—at least in US English.

From Merriam-Webster's definition of [*already*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/already):

> **2** —used as an intensive
>   // All right *already*.
>   // Enough *already*!

---

From [Lexico (Oxford)](https://www.lexico.com/definition/already):

> **2** *North American informal*
>   Used after a word or phrase to express impatience.
>
> ‘just stop already, no one feels sorry for you’
>   ‘We'll start with a plea for this year to just finish already.’
>   ‘Nobody wanted to tell him to just go home already.’
>   ‘If you have a point in saying this, just tell me already.’
>   ‘He needs to just retire already.’
>   ‘I thought this was fine; let's just hurry up already.’

Comment: I'm not a native English speaker. I heard the phrase "Would you please get rid of that filthy couch already?" in a movie and felt that's grammatically incorrect, and ended up here after a bit of Googling. When I hear it, it still irritates inside my head, like the "my bad" phrase. Well, that's something the non-native speakers have to live with I suppose :)

Comment: @ΕГИІИО I'll say that I *personally* don't use the word in that way myself. (But a lot of people do.)

Answer (score 0):

Just some samples from literature:

- Just tell me already.
- Then move me already.
- Miss me already?
- I mean, you trust me already.
- People hate me already.

I think this word can be used this way.

Context of first sentence:

> “Kel?”
> "Colder.” I wasn’t trying to be annoying; I just didn’t know if I was ready to share such fresh, earthshaking news.
> **“Just tell me already.** What?”
> I pressed both hands to my abdomen. “Baby.”

This sentence from the book [Agave Kiss](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/9215658-agave-kiss)

Context of second sentence:

> “Wha?” One eye blinked open.
> “I’ve got to move you.”
> He closed his eye again. **“Then move me already.”**
> “No, not like that. Like off the bed.”

This sentence from the book [Nightshifted](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/12905583-nightshifted).

Comment: if you provide samples, please provide links so that people can check the context.

Comment: The last three are the standard use of _already_. "[Do you] miss me already?" = "Have you started to miss me?" The first two, I think, are the American Jewish usage described by JavaLatte below.

Comment: I did add context of first two sentence.